# create your own table as al list e.g. List of Acronyms

Tags: acronyms

is it possible to create a list of Acronyms as it is with the comment \listoftable?

Comment: Please show what you have tried as an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. Help us to help you.

Comment: Generally speaking: Yes. But if and how depends very much on the way you are handling and marking up your acronyms now.